# NavigationBar barTintColor showing different effect for same color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set color to navigation bar for different controllers but same color showing different effect.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Might be you are giving different color opacity or alpha ?

Comment: no everything is same for both viewcontrollers & navigation controllers

Comment: might be you need to set navigationBar translucent property to No `self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` check if it is working for you.

Comment: Ahh you are just amazing it work for me. Add your code in answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following line to your `viewDidLoad:`method of navigationController class,

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Visit navigationBar [translucent](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624928-translucent) property.